# Convert runnable jar back to eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

Long time ago I exported a eclipse project of mine to a runnable jar. I no longer have the eclipse project but I still have the jar. Is there a way I can convert the jar back to the eclipse project?

Comment: The JAR contains all the .class files (it's basically just a ZIP file), but it doesn't contain any source.

Answer (score 1):

Jars are zip renamed. Try to rename you .jar to .zip and you will be able to have a look at it's content. However, as you will see, it only contains the .class, which are the compiled version of your program. So there is no official way to retrieve the initial code.

You can try to use some decompiler to get an approximative version of the initial code.